# RequireJS: Can two modules require each other?

Tags: javascript, architecture, module, requirejs

Is the following possible with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)?

**Module A:**

```
define([
  'moduleB'
], function(moduleB){

  // log moduleB exports
  console.log(moduleB);


  // exports
  var moduleA = {};


  // set a var to export
  moduleA.varA = 'This is a variable in module A';


  // return exports   
  return moduleA
});
```

**Module B:**

```
define([
  'moduleA'
], function(moduleA){

  // log moduleA exports
  console.log(moduleA);

  // exports
  var moduleB= {};


  // set a var to export
  moduleB.varB= 'This is a variable in module B';



  // return exports
  return moduleB
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

The short answer - you can, but should not.